# Simultaneous Object Calls

Tags: c++, multithreading

If I have shared an object between 2 threads (by passing in a void pointer to the object) what happens if they both try to call (different) methods at the same time? I'm not worried about the member variables themselves, there's a mutex in place for other reasons that luckily covers that already. The main function are calling disjoint methods so there's no possibility of overlap that way, but I wasn't sure what the behavior would be if main calls thing.a() while thread calls thing.b() at the same time (or even if they just overlap for that matter).

Comment: If they don't simultaneously access any member of the object, there shouldn't be any issue. Care to share some example code so we can talk about specifics?

Comment: Functions (including member functions) have no impact on data races in multi-threading. Guarding data (member variables) only, is just right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing special would happen, each thread has its own stack, and each call (even if it was to the same function) would have its own call-frame and its own set of arguments and local variables.

Comment: Cool, that's what I assumed but I wanted to double check because I couldn't find anything definitive